# Two level array sort with one of the second level array members always on top

Tags: ruby, database, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a two level array that has a category and a sub-category in each element like this:

`[[category1, subcategory1], [category1, subcategory2], [category2, subcategory2], [category3, subcategory3]]...`

I'm using this in a dropdown that will show the list like this:

```
category1
  general
  subcategory1
  subcategory2
category2
  general
  subcategory1
  subcategory2
  subcategory3
```

Basically, I need to have the 'general' subcategory to always show up on top of the list of subcategories, if it's present, which are alphabetical. How would I code this?

Using ActiveRecord, it's relatively easy to do an alphabetical sort for the array itself:
`ModelName.pluck(:category, :subcategory).sort`

But that won't put the subcategory 'general' on top. It will be alphabetical. I would prefer a rails solution but any help in pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Is *general* returned after `pluck` or is it just something you want to add to each category afterwards?

Comment: @ndn 'general' is currently one of the subcategories. It's not present in all of the subcategories though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
categorization = ModelName.pluck(:category, :subcategory)
    # => [["category1", "subcategory1"],
    #     ["category1", "subcategory2"],
    #     ["category1", "general"],
    #     ["category2", "general"],
    #     ["category2", "subcategory2"],
    #     ["category3", "subcategory3"],
    #     ["category3", "general"]]


categorization.sort_by! do |category, subcategory|
  subcategory == 'general' ? [category, ''] : [category, subcategory]
end
    # => [["category1", "general"],
    #     ["category1", "subcategory1"],
    #     ["category1", "subcategory2"],
    #     ["category2", "general"],
    #     ["category2", "subcategory2"],
    #     ["category3", "general"],
    #     ["category3", "subcategory3"]]
```

Comment: I tried using your method and it seems that it will unshift all of the 'general' subcategories to the top of the list rather than keeping them within their own categories.

Comment: @JCC, this doesn't make sense. I tried it in pry and it works. Comparison for array compares elements from left to right. Aka it will first compare by `category` and only if the categories are equal will it compare by `subcategory`.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on. I double checked and it does look like it extracts all of the categories with a 'general' subcategory and puts them on top of the list. Not even in order. The rest of the list is ordered however.

Comment: @JCC, could you provide exact output of `p categorization`?

Comment: @JCC, btw `sort_by` does not sort inplace. If you are going to use the `categorization` value afterwards and expect it to be sorted according to the above rule, you should use `sort_by!` instead.

Comment: I posted the output in my question post above. Thanks.

Comment: @JCC, glad to hear that. I added it in my answer. Could you please update the question too, so it wont be confusing for future readers?

Comment: I'm not sure what you need me to change in my question? Let me know and I'll edit. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87413/discussion-between-jcc-and-ndn).

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would format the DB query result, so that it looks like

```
{
  "category1" => ["general", "subcategory1", "subcategory2", ...],
  "category2" => ["general", "subcategory1", "subcategory2", ...],
  ...
}
```

If `"general"` is **not** stored in DB, then

```
ModelName.pluck(:category, :subcategory).sort.reduce(Hash.new{['general']}) do |hash, model|
  hash[model[0]] <<= model[1]
end
```

If `"general"` is in DB, then just remove `"general"` from each array then unshift it:

```
result = ModelName.pluck(:category, :subcategory).sort.reduce(Hash.new{[]}) do |hash, model|
  hash[model[0]] <<= model[1]
end
result.values.each do |subcategories|
  subcategories.unshift('general') if subcategories.delete('general')
end
```